# What response code should be used in case of an attachment containing a virus?

Tags: rest

I am building a REST API that needs to accept a file as a multipart request. The file is then scanned with an antivirus solution. What would be the best response code in case a virus was found ?

Comment: check here http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html 450 suits best as i guess.

Comment: [418](https://httpstatuses.com/418)

Comment: @piyushjaiswal 450 seems Windows specific.

Comment: @peeskillet In wiki it says "418 is not expected to be implemented by actual HTTP servers."

Comment: @panagdu, it was a joke :-)